# Windows Powershell - delete a line by line number

Tags: powershell, file

I have a large csv file (1.6gb). how can I delete a specific line e.g. line 1005?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<sup>Note: The solutions below eliminate a single line from any text-based file by line number. As [marsze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2060966/marsze) points out, additional considerations may apply to *CSV* files, where care must be taken not to eliminate the header row, and rows may span multiple lines if they have values with embedded newlines; use of a CSV parser is a better choice in that case.</sup>

If performance isn't paramount, here's a **memory-friendly pipeline-based way** to do it:

```sh
Get-Content file.txt | 
  Where-Object ReadCount -ne 1005 |
    Set-Content -Encoding Utf8 new-file.txt
```

`Get-Content` adds a (somewhat obscurely named) `.ReadCount` property to each line it outputs, which contains the `1`-based line number.

- Note that the input file's character encoding isn't preserved by `Get-Content`, so you should control `Set-Content`'st output encoding explicitly, as shown above, using UTF-8 as an example.
- Without reading the whole file into memory as a whole, you must output to a *new* file, at least temporarily; you can replace the original file with the temporary output file with
  `Move-Item -Force new-file.txt file.txt`

---

A **faster, but memory-intensive alternative** based on direct use of the .NET framework, which also allows you to update the file in place:

```sh
$file = 'file.txt'
$lines = [IO.File]::ReadAllLines("$PWD/$file")
Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 $file -Value $lines[0..1003 + 1005..($lines.Count-1)]
```

- Note the need to use `"$PWD/$file"`, i.e., to explicitly prepend the current directory path to the relative path stored in `$file`, because the .NET framework's idea of what the current directory is differs from PowerShell's.

  - While `$lines = Get-Content $file` would be functionally equivalent to `$lines = [IO.File]::ReadAllLines("$PWD/$file")`, it would perform noticeably poorer.
- `0..1003` creates an array of indices from `0` to `1003`; `+` concatenates that array with indices `1005` through the rest of the input array; note that array indices are `0`-based, whereas line numbers are `1`-based.
- Also note how the resulting array is passed to `Set-Content` as a *direct argument* via `-Value`, which is faster than passing it via the pipeline (`... | Set-Content ...`), where element-by-element processing would be performed.

---

Finally, **a memory-friendly method that is faster than the pipeline-based method**:

```sh
$file = 'file.txt'
$outFile = [IO.File]::CreateText("$PWD/new-file.txt")
$lineNo = 0
try {
  foreach ($line in [IO.File]::ReadLines("$PWD/$file")) {
    if (++$lineNo -eq 1005) { continue }
    $outFile.WriteLine($line)
  }
} finally {
  $outFile.Dispose()
}
```

<sup>Note the use of `"$PWD/..."` in the .NET API calls, which ensures that a *full* path is passed, which is necessary, because .NET's working directory usually differs from PowerShell's.</sup>

As with the pipeline-based command, you may have to replace the original file with the new file afterwards.