# PowerShell Core. Relative path issue

Tags: .net, powershell, .net-core, powershell-core

PowerShell:

```
$file = "text.txt"
Test-Path $file            
# True
 
Get-Location
# C:\Users\Fors1k

[IO.File]::OpenRead($file) 
# FileStream
 
[IO.FileInfo]::new($file)  
# Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                         
# ----                 -------------         ------ ----                         
# -a----        05.03.2021     18:12              7 text.txt  
                      
gc $file                   
# test123
```

Everything is ok.

PowerShell Core:

```
$file = "text.txt"
Test-Path $file            
# True
 
Get-Location
# C:\Users\Fors1k

[IO.File]::OpenRead($file) 
# Exception calling "OpenRead" with "1" argument(s): "Could not find file 'C:\Windows\system32\text.txt'."
 
[IO.FileInfo]::new($file)  
# Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                         
# ----                 -------------         ------ ----
# larhs          01.01.1601     3:00  
                      
gc $file                   
# test123
```

Here i got errors.

As i understand, problem is that the .NET methods think, that current location is sysfolder, not real current location.

Responding to recommendations:

I understand, that there are many solutions:

```
$file = "text.txt"
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = Get-Location
[IO.File]::OpenRead($file)
#
#
$file = "text.txt"
[IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory((Get-Location))
[IO.File]::OpenRead($file)
#
#
$file = "text.txt"
$file = Convert-Path $file
[IO.File]::OpenRead($file)
#
#
# My solution, before asking, was
$file = "text.txt"
$file = Get-Item $file
[IO.File]::OpenRead($file)
```

But all of this is "fix on the go"(I don't know the correct English idiom for this phrase).

I mean, why this works normally on posh 5.1?

Why this code: `[IO.File]::OpenRead("text.txt")` works on pwsh my friends, which ones I asked?

Maybe there is still a setting like (exaggerating):`[DotNet.Path]::SetDefaultLocation("TheSameAsPwsh")`

@mathias-r-jessen , got your point:

**[Environment]::CurrentDirectory** and **Get-Location** is a initially unrelated things.

PowerShell:

```
"$(Get-Location)" -eq ([Environment]::CurrentDirectory)
# True
##
##
Set-Location ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("desktop"))

"$(Get-Location)" -eq ([Environment]::CurrentDirectory)
# False (!!!)
```

So, my question with an understanding of what is happening:

Why my pwsh has `[Environment]::CurrentDirectory` as C:\Windows\system32, and is it possible to change this **default** value to user folder like it is in posh?

Comment: PowerShell and .NET each have their own independent "current directory". You can synchronize them as described in the answer below or use `Convert-Path` to pass absolute path to .NET API: `[IO.File]::OpenRead((Convert-Path $file))`. Note double parentheses to call PS expression as argument for .NET function.

Comment: You may also write `[IO.File]::OpenRead("$PWD/$file")` as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54074199/7571258)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing locations in PowerShell doesn't automatically update the process' working directory - which is what .NET uses to resolve relative paths internally.

As [Joma's answer excellently suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66498928/712649), you can solve this by updating `[Environment]::CurrentDirectory` before invoking the method.

If you find yourself running into this issue often when using PowerShell interactively, add a mechanism for updating it to [your prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts) (the following example is lifted straight out of one of my own [profile scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles)) - this will keep the two "in sync":

```
$function:prompt = {
  if($PWD.Provider -eq 'FileSystem'){
    [Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $PWD.Path
  }

  "PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation -replace [regex]::Escape($HOME),'~')$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) "
}
```

Comment: @Fors1k I understand your confoundment, but the answer to the question "why this works normally on posh 5.1?" is that when you launch `powershell.exe` from explorer, the directory defaults to your user profile - try navigating to _any other path_ than `C:\Users\Fors1k` and you'll run into the same problem again. How are you launching `pwsh.exe`?

Comment: @Fors1k You didn't answer my question, _how are you launching `pwsh`_? If you're using a shortcut (whether from your desktop, start menu or task bar), simply update the shortcut to launch the process with the desired working directory (right-click -> Properties -> Shortcut -> change "Start in" value to `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` for example)

Comment: @Joma You might want to "restore" the original value at the end of your script when setting it to `$PSScriptRoot` (like `$original = [Environment]::CurrentDirectory;[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $PSScriptRoot; try{ <# rest of script #>}finally{ [Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $original }` or similar)

Comment: You can use Push-Location and Pop-location with try-finally to avoid this disaster. My answer is a short example.

Answer (score 6):

Change the current working directory for .NET.

```
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = "$(Get-Location)"
```

or

```
[System.IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory("$(Get-Location)")
```

**Alternative code - Same result**
Your code uses Streams. You should free/close the stream resources at end, with try -finally.

```
$file = "text.txt"


if (! (Test-Path $file -PathType Leaf)) {
    New-Item $file
}

Get-Content $file
```

**[File.OpenRead(String path) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openread?view=net-5.0)**
*Remarks*
The path parameter is permitted to specify relative or absolute path information. Relative path information is interpreted as relative to the current working directory. To obtain the current working directory, see [GetCurrentDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory?view=net-5.0).

**[Directory.GetCurrentDirectory Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory?view=net-5.0)**
*Remarks*
The current directory is **distinct** from the original directory, which is the one from which the process was started.

Checking this method in pwsh.exe and powershell.exe. The returned values are different. I think that each one has a different implementation.
[image: pwsh]
[image: Windows PowerShell]

if you run your code from script file. i.e. **./Script.ps1**
You can use **$PSScriptroot** global variable, it contains the path of the directory where the script is running.

```
Write-Host "ScriptPath: $PSScriptroot"
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = "$PSScriptroot"
Write-Host "CurrentDirectory: $([Environment]::CurrentDirectory)"
```

[image: pwsh]

Comment: You can simplify the statements as the stringification is not required: `[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = Get-Location` and `[System.IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory((Get-Location))`